# Unable to Correct Oracle Error ORA-00905 Missing Keyword in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, case, where-clause

I've been grinding on this small snippet of simple code for a day and can't find the issue causing the error.  As the title states, I am getting error `ORA-00905 Missing Keyword` when trying to execute the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DM.DESCRIPTION                 AS "AGENCY",
                DM.DEPT_NO                     AS "DEPT NO",
                CASE
                    WHEN VMP.RESERVE_DT IS NULL THEN
                        NULL
                    ELSE
                        VMP.RESERVE_DT
                END AS "RESV_DT",
                CASE
                    WHEN VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT IS NULL THEN
                        NULL
                    ELSE
                        VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT
                END AS "EST_PKUP_DT",
                CASE
                    WHEN VMP.EST_RETURN_DT IS NULL THEN
                        NULL
                    ELSE
                        VMP.EST_RETURN_DT
                END AS "EST_RETN_DT",
                VMP.EMP_NAME                   AS "EMPL_NAME",
                VMP.UNIT_NO                    AS "UNIT_NUMBER",
                VMP.RENTAL_CLASS_DESCRIPTION   AS "RENT_CLS",
                VMP.MP_TICKET_NO               AS "MP_TKT_NO"
  FROM DEPT_MAIN DM
 INNER JOIN VIEW_MPOOL VMP ON VMP.DEPT_ID = DM.DEPT_ID
 WHERE CASE
           WHEN VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT IS NULL THEN
               NULL
           ELSE
               TRUNC(VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
       END
 GROUP BY DM.DESCRIPTION,
          DM.DEPT_NO,
          CASE
              WHEN VMP.RESERVE_DT IS NULL THEN
                  NULL
              ELSE
                  VMP.RESERVE_DT
          END,
          CASE
              WHEN VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT IS NULL THEN
                  NULL
              ELSE
                  VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT
          END,
          CASE
              WHEN VMP.EST_RETURN_DT IS NULL THEN
                  NULL
              ELSE
                  VMP.EST_RETURN_DT
          END,
          VMP.EMP_NAME,
          VMP.UNIT_NO,
          VMP.RENTAL_CLASS_DESCRIPTION,
          VMP.MP_TICKET_NO
 ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT IS NULL THEN
        NULL
    ELSE
        VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT
END ASC
```

The basis of this code was generated through an adhoc reporting program and was originally fully-qualified.  I stripped out the extraneous quotation marks and assigned table aliases to clean it up.  Though I hoped these efforts would help me find the issue, I am unable to find the cause.  Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: You rarely never need to do SELECT DISTINCT when GROUP BY.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve first.

Comment: Your CASE expression are useless: `CASE WHEN VMP.RESERVE_DT IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE VMP.RESERVE_DT END` is the same as `VMP.RESERVE_DT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace this :

```
WHERE 
    CASE 
        WHEN VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT IS NULL THEN NULL 
        ELSE TRUNC(VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT) = TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
    END
```

With :

```
WHERE 
    CASE 
        WHEN VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT IS NULL THEN NULL 
        ELSE TRUNC(VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT) 
    END 
    = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

Please note that this whole expression (and others similar in the query) could be simplified as as :

```
WHERE
    TRUNC(VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

When `VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT` is `NULL`, `TRUNC` will return `NULL`, which will not be equal to `TRUNC(SYSDATE)`.

Comment: @EzLo your answer was neck-and-neck with GMB but his showed up first so I gave it the Solve.  Your answers were functionally identical so I did give both upvotes.  Thanks to both of you for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
WHERE 
    CASE 
        WHEN VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT IS NULL 
        THEN NULL 
        ELSE TRUNC(VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT) = TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
    END
```

The `END` is after a comparison and the case is not being compared against a value.

Switch it like:

```
WHERE 
    CASE 
        WHEN VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT IS NULL 
        THEN NULL 
        ELSE TRUNC(VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT)
    END = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

Which as horse says, can just be simplified as

```
WHERE TRUNC(VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

since a `NULL` value on `VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT` will never match `TRUNC(SYSDATE)`.

Comment: That can be simplified to `where TRUNC(VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name correct, I was busy checking syntax and not semantics.

Answer (score 1):

> can't find the issue causing the error

Although I suppose that @EzLo and @a_horse_with_no_name maybe already found error in this case, I can propose a **general** procedure in debugging such queries.

## Step 1: Debug your JOIN- and WHERE- predicates

Comment everything in your SELECT-statement, leave only JOINs, substitute fields with `*` or constant expression.

E.g.

```
SELECT 1 
    -- DISTINCT DM.DESCRIPTION                 AS "AGENCY",
    --             DM.DEPT_NO                     AS "DEPT NO",
    --             CASE
    -- ....
    --             VMP.RENTAL_CLASS_DESCRIPTION   AS "RENT_CLS",
    --             VMP.MP_TICKET_NO               AS "MP_TKT_NO"
FROM DEPT_MAIN DM
INNER JOIN VIEW_MPOOL VMP ON VMP.DEPT_ID = DM.DEPT_ID
WHERE CASE
        WHEN VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT IS NULL THEN
            NULL
        ELSE
            TRUNC(VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
    END
--  GROUP BY DM.DESCRIPTION,
--  ....
--  ORDER BY ..
```

In case of multiple complex predicates - uncomment one predicate at a time.

## Step 2: Debug your GROUP BYs and HAVINGs

Uncomment GROUP BY section and edit fields section of your query.
If you have complex groupby's - uncomment by one field at time. 
Start from simplest to complex

```
SELECT
        DM.DESCRIPTION
        ,DM.DEPT_NO    
    -- ...
FROM DEPT_MAIN DM
INNER JOIN VIEW_MPOOL VMP ON VMP.DEPT_ID = DM.DEPT_ID
WHERE CASE
        WHEN VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT IS NULL THEN
            NULL
        ELSE
            TRUNC(VMP.EST_PICKUP_DT) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
    END
GROUP BY DM.DESCRIPTION
        ,DM.DEPT_NO
```

Copy-paste your GROUP BYs into SELECT fields section.

## Step 3: Debug you aggregates, field transformation and renames

Now you have correct SELECT-query but probably not in the shape you want.

## Step 4: Debug ORDER BYs

You have correct shape and in last step you need to ORDER BY your data.

If you have decent editor/IDE you can find source of error in 5-10 minutes even in cases of complex queries (and even RDBMS engine bugs)

#### P.S.

It's better to note which version of RDBMS you are using.

Comment: I use a similar process and there were other errors that were resolved prior to posting.  I looked right at the CASE END statement and didn't see the issue.  Thank you for the suggestion!